# .h265 stream decoding browserside in Chrome 114

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, codec

I am trying to write a webpage that can take a h265 stream coming from a websocket, and display it on the webpage. I've heard that [Chrome>107 supports .h265 video encoding](https://flussonic.com/doc/video-playback/playing-h-265/), but I've been unable to find any documentation on it anywhere. Is there an Javascript facing API that can be used to decode .h265 packets in Chrome?